# How to estimate altitude of tropopause of other planets?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, atmosphere-modelling, inversion, stratosphere

Is it possible to come up with a formula to estimate the height of the tropopause and the upper layer lapse rate only based on atmospheric composition and other atmospheric parameters (not relying on atmospheric sounding data)?

Comment: Note that even Earth's varies quite a bit, as [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropopause), varying from 9 km average at the Poles to 17 km average at the Equator, basically due to temperature -> density differences.

Comment: A good read on this topic is https://doi.org/10.1017/9781107588417 chapter 15.5. In short: You can get estimates if you have some understanding of the planets atmosphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence, and accordingly the height, of a tropopause depends on whether the other planets' atmosphere has a layer of ozone or any other gas that absorbs some part of incoming solar radiation leading to a substantial heating and, hence, a significant temperature inversion.

Given an atmospheric composition, to attain some numerical values for the tropopause height and the lapse rate probably requires modelling of radiative transfer, which is a notoriously difficult task.